# How do I connect to a remote URL in Scala which requires authentication?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using the following code --

```
val url = new URL(LoginUrl)
val connection = url.openConnection()
val userpass = login + ":" + passwd
val auth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()))
connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", auth)
val page = connection.getInputStream()
Logger.debug("Page   " +page )
```

But the only thing I am getting is --

```
[debug] application - Page   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@33f13d38
```

EDIT: Based on the comments I read the stream, I get the page. But I get the login page. I want the page which I get after log-in. What else needs to be done?

```
var writer = new StringWriter()
IOUtils.copy(page, writer, "UTF-8")
var htmlString = writer.toString()
Logger.debug("Page   " + htmlString)
```

The login URL is `"https://affiliate-program.amazon.in/gp/associates/network/main.html"`

The html page I get --

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
        <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">

    <head>

    <title>
        Amazon Sign In 
    </title>
    <link  type="text/css" href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/x-locale/common/errors-alerts/error-styles-ssl._CB138362389_.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link  type="text/css" href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/authportal/common/css/ap_global._CB350157780_.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>  
    </head>

    <body id="amzn_associates_in" class="ap-locale-en_IN" >

    <!--[if lte IE 5]>
    <div class="ie">
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <div class="ie ie6">
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <div class="ie ie7">
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <div class="ie ie8">
    <![endif]-->

    <div id="headerbanner">

    </div>

    <div id="wrapper"> 

    <div id="navbarTopSlots">


    </div>

    <div id="topSlots">
      <div id="top-0"></div>
      <div id="top-1">

    <div id="ap_header" class="ap_header">

          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/x-locale/common/amazon-logo._CB138360615_.gif" height="36" alt="Amazon Logo" width="126" border="0"/>


    </div>
    </div>
      <div id="top-2"></div>
      <div id="top-3"></div>
      <div id="top-4"></div>
      <div id="top-5"></div>
      <div id="top-6"></div>
      <div id="top-7"></div>
      <div id="top-8"></div>
      <div id="top-9"></div>
      <div id="top-10"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="leftSlots">
      <div id="left-0"></div>
      <div id="left-1"></div>
      <div id="left-2"></div>
      <div id="left-3"></div>
      <div id="left-4"></div>
      <div id="left-5"></div>
      <div id="left-6"></div>
      <div id="left-7"></div>
      <div id="left-8"></div>
      <div id="left-9"></div>
      <div id="left-10"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="centerSlots">
      <div id="center-0"></div>

      <div id="title-slot">

    <!--[if lte IE 5]>
    <div class="ie">
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <div class="ie ie6">
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <div class="ie ie7">
    <![endif]-->  

    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <div class="ie ie8">
    <![endif]-->  
        <div id="ap_title_pagelet">

        </div>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    </div>
    <![endif]-->    

    </div>

      <div id="message-box-slot">

            <div id="message_warning" class="message warning" style="display:none">
                <span></span>
                <h6>Please Enable Cookies to Continue</h6>
                <p>
                    To continue shopping at Amazon, please enable cookies in your Web browser.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=ap_cookie_error_help??nodeId=200168080" target="AmazonHelp" onclick="return amz_js_PopWin(this.href,'AmazonHelp','width=700,height=800,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,toolbar=1,status=1');return false;"  >
                        Learn more
                    </a>                                                
                    about cookies and how to enable them.
                </p>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
                {
                    var exdate=new Date();
                    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
                    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
                    ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
                }

                function getCookie(c_name)
                {
                    if (document.cookie.length>0)
                    {
                        c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
                        if (c_start!=-1)
                        {
                            c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
                            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
                            if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
                            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
                        }
                    }
                    return "";
                }
                function deleteCookie ( cookie_name )
                {
                  var cookie_date = new Date ( );  // current date & time
                  cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
                  document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
                }

                function checkCookieEnabled(nodeId)
                {
                    setCookie('amznTest','1',null);
                    if(getCookie('amznTest')){
                        deleteCookie('amznTest');
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById(nodeId).style.display = 'block';
                    }
                }
                checkCookieEnabled('message_warning');
            </script>                           


    </div>

      <div id="center-1"></div>

          <div id="signin-slot">

    <script>

          function cf() {
            if (typeof window.uet === 'function') {
              uet('cf');
            }
            if (window.embedNotification &&
              typeof window.embedNotification.onCF === 'function') {
              embedNotification.onCF();
            }
          }

    </script>

    <!--[if lte IE 5]>
        <div class="ie">
          <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 6]>
        <div class="ie ie6">
          <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <div class="ie ie7">
          <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <div class="ie ie8">
          <![endif]-->

    <form name="signIn" method="POST" id="ap_signin_form" novalidate="novalidate" action="https://www.amazon.in/ap/signin"





            onsubmit="var test1 = apCheckRequiredFields('ap_signin_form', ['ap_email','ap_password']);
            return (apValidateEmail('ap_email') && test1);"



      >





          <input type="hidden" name="appActionToken" value="scIhj2FOCtxr39z7eUIj2FWeNOWxtIwj3D" /><input type="hidden" name="appAction" value="SIGNIN" />

            <input type="hidden" name="openid.pape.max_auth_age" value="ape:MA==" />

            <input type="hidden" name="openid.ns" value="ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjA=" />

            <input type="hidden" name="openid.ns.pape" value="ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy9wYXBlLzEuMA==" />

            <input type="hidden" name="prevRID" value="ape:MEhOWlBQUjQ3Rzg0U1QwREJTRVo=" />

            <input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="ape:YW16bl9hc3NvY2lhdGVzX2lu" />

            <input type="hidden" name="openid.identity" value="ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=" />

            <input type="hidden" name="openid.claimed_id" value="ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=" />

            <input type="hidden" name="openid.mode" value="ape:Y2hlY2tpZF9zZXR1cA==" />

            <input type="hidden" name="openid.assoc_handle" value="ape:YW16bl9hc3NvY2lhdGVzX2lu" />

            <input type="hidden" name="openid.return_to" value="ape:aHR0cHM6Ly9hZmZpbGlhdGUtcHJvZ3JhbS5hbWF6b24uaW4vZ3AvYXNzb2NpYXRlcy9uZXR3b3JrL21haW4uaHRtbD9pZT1VVEY4JipWZXJzaW9uKj0xJiplbnRyaWVzKj0w" />





      <div id="ap_signin1a_pagelet" class="ap_table ap_pagelet">


        <div id="ap_signin1a_pagelet_title" class="ap_row ap_pagelet_title">
          <h1>Sign In</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="ap_signin1a_email_section_title" class="ap_row ap_section_title">
          <h2>

                What is your e-mail address?

          </h2>
        </div>

        <div id="ap_signin1a_email_row" class="ap_row">

              <span class="ap_col1 ap_bold ap_right ap_no_collapse">
                <label for="ap_email">

                      My e-mail address is:

                </label>
              </span>
 <span class="ap_col2 ap_left">
            <input id="ap_email" name="email" value="" type="email" size="30" maxlength="128" tabindex="1" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" />   
          </span>
        </div>

        <div id="ap_signin_custom_message" class="center clear-both" >

        </div>
 <div id="ap_signin1a_password_section_title" class="ap_row ap_section_title">
              <h2> Do you have an Amazon password? </h2>
            </div>


            <div id="ap_signin1a_new_cust_radio_row" class="ap_row">
              <span id="" class="ap_col1 ap_right ap_no_collapse">
                <input type="radio" onclick="setElementAvailability('ap_password', false);jQuery('#ap_captcha_table').hide();" name="create" id="ap_signin_create_radio" value="1" tabindex="6"  />
              </span>
              <span id="" class="ap_col2 bold ap_radio_label">
                <label for="ap_signin_create_radio">I am a new customer.</label>
                <div class="small">(you'll create a password later)</div>
              </span>
            </div>


            <div id="ap_signin1a_exist_cust_radio_row" class="ap_row">
              <span class="ap_col1 ap_right" >
                <input type="radio" name="create" onclick="setElementAvailability('ap_password', true);jQuery('#ap_captcha_table').show();" id="ap_signin_existing_radio" value="0" tabindex="7" checked="checked" />
              </span>
              <span class="ap_col2 bold ap_radio_label"><label for="ap_signin_existing_radio">I am a returning customer&#44; <br>and my password is&#58;</label></span>
            </div>




            <div id="ap_signin1a_password_row" class="ap_row">
              <span class="ap_col1">&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="ap_col2">
                <input id="ap_password" name="password" type="password" maxlength="1024" size="20"  tabindex="2" onkeypress="displayCapsWarning(event,'ap_caps_warning', this);" class="password"/>
              </span>

              <span id="ap_caps_warn_span">







    <div id="ap_caps_warning" class="ap_caps_warn ap_col3_caps_warn" style="visibility:hidden;"> 
      <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <style type="text/css">
      .ap_caps_warn {
        display: none;
      }
      </style>
      <![endif]-->
      <b>Caps Lock is on.</b> <font color="black">This may cause you <br>to enter your password incorrectly.</font>
    </div>

              </span>
            </div>

            <!--[if IE]><![if !IE]><![endif]-->
              <div id="ap_small_forgot_password_link">
            <!--[if IE]><![endif]><![endif]-->
            <!--[if lte IE 6]>
              <div id="ap_small_forgot_password_link_ie_old" class="ie_old">
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if gte IE 7]>
               <div id="ap_small_forgot_password_link_ie_new" class="ie_new">
            <![endif]-->
                <span class="small" id="ap_small_forgot_password_span">
                  <a href="https://www.amazon.in/ap/forgotpassword?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&prevRID=0HNZPPR47G84ST0DBSEZ&pageId=amzn_associates_in&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_associates_in&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Faffiliate-program.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fassociates%2Fnetwork%2Fmain.html%3Fie%3DUTF8%26*Version*%3D1%26*entries*%3D0"></a>
                </span>
              </div>

        <div id="ap_signin1a_signin_button_row" class="ap_row">
          <span class="ap_col1">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="ap_col2">
 <input type="image" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/x-locale/common/buttons/sign-in-secure._CB138348554_.gif"  id="signInSubmit" height="22" onload="cf()" alt="Continue" width="201" tabindex="5" value="Continue" border="0" />


          </span>
          <div class="ap_csm_marker" style="display:none;">

            <script type="text/javascript">if (typeof uet == 'function') { uet('af'); }</script>
          </div>
        </div>
<div id="ap_signin1a_forgot_password_row" class="ap_row">
          <span class="ap_col1">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="ap_col2">
 <a href="https://www.amazon.in/ap/forgotpassword?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&prevRID=0HNZPPR47G84ST0DBSEZ&pageId=amzn_associates_in&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_associates_in&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Faffiliate-program.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fassociates%2Fnetwork%2Fmain.html%3Fie%3DUTF8%26*Version*%3D1%26*entries*%3D0">
                  Forgot your password?
                </a>


          </span>
        </div>
 <div id="ap_signin1a_cnep_row" class="ap_row">
            <span class="ap_col1">&nbsp;</span>
            <span id="ap_signin1a_cnep_row_col2" class="ap_col2">
              <a href="https://www.amazon.in/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&prevRID=0HNZPPR47G84ST0DBSEZ&pageId=amzn_associates_in&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_associates_in&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Faffiliate-program.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fassociates%2Fnetwork%2Fmain.html%3Fie%3DUTF8%26*Version*%3D1%26*entries*%3D0&changeEmail=1">Has your e-mail address changed since your last order?</a>
            </span>
          </div>
 </div>
    </form>

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        </div>
    <![endif]-->
    </div>
      <div id="center-2"></div>
      <div id="center-3"></div>
      <div id="center-4"></div>
      <div id="center-5"></div>
      <div id="center-6"></div>
      <div id="center-7"></div>
      <div id="center-8"></div>
      <div id="center-9"></div>
      <div id="center-10"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="rightSlots">
      <div id="right-0"></div>
      <div id="right-1"></div>
      <div id="right-2"></div>
      <div id="right-3"></div>
      <div id="right-4"></div>
      <div id="right-5"></div>
      <div id="right-6"></div>
      <div id="right-7"></div>
      <div id="right-8"></div>
      <div id="right-9"></div>
      <div id="right-10"></div>
    </div>



    <div id="bottomSlots">
      <div id="bottom-1">



    <div id="ap_privacy" class="ap_privacy_footer">
      <p class="tiny" align="center">
        <a id="footer_conditions_of_use_URL_link" href="/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=ap_footer_condition_of_use?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=200545940" onclick="return amz_js_PopWin(this.href+'&pop-up=1','AmazonHelp','width=340,height=340,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,toolbar=1,status=1');" target="AmazonHelp" >Conditions of Use</a>
        <a id="footer_privacy_notice_URL_link" href="/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=ap_footer_privacy_notice?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=200534380" onclick="return amz_js_PopWin(this.href+'&pop-up=1','AmazonHelp','width=340,height=340,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,toolbar=1,status=1');" target="AmazonHelp" >Privacy Notice</a>

        <br>
        <span id="ap_footer_copyright">© 1996-2015, Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div id="bottom-2"></div>
      <div id="bottom-3"></div>
      <div id="bottom-4"></div>
      <div id="bottom-5"></div>
      <div id="bottom-6"></div>
      <div id="bottom-7"></div>
      <div id="bottom-8"></div>
      <div id="bottom-9"></div>
      <div id="bottom-10"></div>  
    </div>

    <div id="footerSlots">
      <div id="footer-1"></div><!-- footer-1 -->
      <div id="footer-2"></div><!-- footer-2 -->
      <div id="footer-3"></div><!-- footer-3 -->
      <div id="footer-4"></div><!-- footer-4 -->
      <div id="footer-5"></div><!-- footer-5 -->
      <div id="footer-6"></div><!-- footer-6 -->
      <div id="footer-7"></div><!-- footer-7 -->
      <div id="footer-8"></div><!-- footer-8 -->
      <div id="footer-9"></div><!-- footer-9 -->
      <div id="footer-10"></div><!-- footer-10 -->

    </div><!-- footerSlots -->

    <div id="navbarBottomSlots">


    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function() {
        try {
          if ( ue && ue.tag && window.performance.getEntriesByType ) {
            var t = window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource');
            if ( t ) {
              var d = 0;
              for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
                if ( t[i].duration > d ) d = t[i].duration;
              ue.tag('ap-rt-' + Math.ceil(d / 100) * 100);
            }
          }
        }
        catch (e) {}
        })();

    </script>


    <div id="javascriptSlots">

    <div id="javascript-slot-0">





        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/javascripts/lib/jquery/jquery-1.2.6.min._CB166146506_.js"></script>



    </div>
    <div id="javascript-slot-1"></div>
    <div id="javascript-slot-2"></div>
    <div id="javascript-slot-3"></div>
    <div id="javascript-slot-4"></div>

    <div id="javascript-identity">





        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/authportal/common/js/ap_global-1.1._CB309255203_.js"></script>



    </div>
    <div id="javascript-slot-5"></div>

    <div id="js-trms">




    <script id="fwcim-script" type="text/javascript" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/x-locale/common/login/fwcim._CB342129342_.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    fwcim.useMercury('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/x-locale/common/login/mercury9._CB372126299_.swf')


    fwcim.profile();

    </script>
    </div>

    <div id="cache-1"></div>
    <div id="cache-2"></div>
    </div><!-- javascriptSlots -->

    </div> <!-- end  div  wrapper -->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    </div>
    <![endif]-->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And what are you expecting?

Comment: It's a stream. You need to read something from it.

Comment: `connection.getInputStream()` returns, well a `Stream`. So your code is working. You need to read from the stream. Also, you could try a library like Play WS to make HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

`connection.getInputStream()` returns an InputStream. So you need to read from the InputStream. A good way to read from the InputStream and convert it to string would be

```
val page = connection.getInputStream()
val pageString = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(page).getLines().mkString("\n")
```